# How to use apt-get on BasilOS?

Tags: apt, application, deb

I have recently upgrade from BasilOS Trinity to BasilOS Quad. In Quad apt-get was integrated, I read some documentation on it, but I still do not fully understand if it is meant to be used with .deb files or software repos/catalogs. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get` is like an advanced version of `dpkg`. As BasilOS is based off of Ubuntu, `apt-get` is a very useful command. 
What it does is references the canonical software repo and other PPAs (if manually added). `apt-get` can be used by either running `root`* and then `apt-get install appName` or `sudo apt-get install appName`. You can also use `sudo apt-get install appName.deb`. 
* I believe that `root` is solely on  BasilOS, for other Linux OSes, run `su` or `sudo -i`. 
This description is *very brief* and does not cover `apt-get remove`, `apt-get upgrade`, or `apt-get update`... There is also `apt-cache`! I recommend for a more in depth answer use the man pages.

Comment: "apt-get is like an advanced version of dpkg". No offense, but that isn't accurate and somewhat vague.